Why did the DIME Protocol (Dark Internet Mail Environment) never become widespread?
Why did the DIME Protocol (Dark Internet Mail Environment) never become widespread?
The protocol was marketed pretty well in the news and had some bigger names/support at the time. But, alas, in 2024 it appears to be irrelevant and I do not know a single major privacy focused mail provider that utilizes it.
What happened to the DIME Protocol? Is something wrong with the standard?
